# XmlSerializer and IEnumerable: Serialization possible w/o parameterless constructor: Bug?

Tags: .net, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

In our project we extensivly use the XmlSerializer. By chance I found a class w/o a parameterless contructor. I thought this must break the serialization process but it did not.

By investigating this issue I found out, that the XmlSerializer behaves strange when serializing/deserializing an *IEnumerable*:

- All elements of the enumerable are serialized
- The class is required to implement an *Add(object)* method
- It ignores all other properties that may be in this class.
- It calls a getter with this property and reuses the returned instance for serialization (which allows the XmlSerializer to work w/o a parameterless constructor).

Please have a look at the example that follows. Intersting parts are ODD1, ODD2. Note that good5 and good6 are false, when I expected them to be true.

Is there a reason for this behaviour?

Can I make XmlSerializer reuse an instance returned by a property for deserialization when implementing IXmlSerializable by hand?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;   
using System.IO;    
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Test
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            HostingClass host = new HostingClass();

            host.AutomaticSerialization.StringProperty = "AUTO";
            host.SelfImplementedSerialization.StringProperty = "SELF";

            bool good1 = host.AutomaticSerialization.FromConstructor == "PARAMETER";
            bool good2 = host.SelfImplementedSerialization.FromConstructor == "PARAMETER";
            bool good3 = host.AutomaticSerialization.StringProperty == "AUTO";
            bool good4 = host.SelfImplementedSerialization.StringProperty == "SELF";

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(HostingClass));

            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                serializer.Serialize(sw, host);

                using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString()))
                {
                    host = (HostingClass)serializer.Deserialize(sr);
                }
            }

            bool good5 = host.AutomaticSerialization.FromConstructor == null; //is false
            bool good6 = host.AutomaticSerialization.StringProperty == "AUTO"; //is false

            bool good7 = host.SelfImplementedSerialization.FromConstructor == null;
            bool good8 = host.SelfImplementedSerialization.StringProperty == "SELF";

        }
    }

    public class HostingClass
    {
        private SelfImplementedSerialization _selfImplementedSerialization;
        public SelfImplementedSerialization SelfImplementedSerialization
        {
            get
            {
                return _selfImplementedSerialization
                       ?? (_selfImplementedSerialization = new SelfImplementedSerialization("PARAMETER"));
            }
            set { _selfImplementedSerialization = value; }
        }

        private AutomaticSerialization _automaticSerialization;
        public AutomaticSerialization AutomaticSerialization
        {
            get
            {
                return _automaticSerialization
                       ?? (_automaticSerialization = new AutomaticSerialization("PARAMETER")); //the returned object is used while deserializing
            }
            set { _automaticSerialization = value; }
        }
    }

    public class SelfImplementedSerialization : IXmlSerializable, IEnumerable<int>
    {
        public SelfImplementedSerialization() { }
        public SelfImplementedSerialization(string parameter)
        {
            FromConstructor = parameter;
        }

        public string StringProperty { get; set; }
        [XmlIgnore]
        public string FromConstructor { get; set; }

        public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        {
            reader.ReadStartElement();
            StringProperty = reader.ReadElementString("StringProperty");
            reader.ReadEndElement();
        }

        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteElementString("StringProperty", StringProperty);
        }

        public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
        {
            yield return 1;
            yield return 2;
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }
        public XmlSchema GetSchema() { return null; }
    }


    public class AutomaticSerialization : IEnumerable<int>
    {
        //ODD1: Serialization possible w/o public parameterless constructor
        //public AutomaticSerialization() {} 
        public AutomaticSerialization(string parameter)
        {
            FromConstructor = parameter;
        }

        //ODD2: Element not serialized, only the IEnumerable Interface is serialized
        [XmlElement("SP")]
        public string StringProperty { get; set; }
        [XmlIgnore]
        public string FromConstructor { get; set; }

        public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
        {
            yield return 1;
            yield return 2;
        }

        public void Add(object o)
        {
            //requirement of XmlSerializer when serializing IEnumerables
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for the behavior is that this is the way it has always worked.

From [XmlSerializer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx):

> **Note**
>
> The `XmlSerializer` gives special
>   treatment to classes that implement
>   `IEnumerable` or `ICollection`. A class
>   that implements `IEnumerable` must
>   implement a public Add method that
>   takes a single parameter. The Add
>   method's parameter must be of the same
>   type as is returned from the `Current`
>   property on the value returned from
>   `GetEnumerator`, or one of that type's
>   bases. A class that implements
>   `ICollection` (such as `CollectionBase`)
>   in addition to `IEnumerable` must have a
>   public Item indexed property (indexer
>   in C#) that takes an integer, and it
>   must have a public Count property of
>   type integer. The parameter to the Add
>   method must be the same type as is
>   returned from the Item property, or
>   one of that type's bases. For classes
>   that implement `ICollection`, values to
>   be serialized are retrieved from the
>   indexed Item property, not by calling
>   `GetEnumerator`.

Comment: Hey John, thanks for the answer. Do you have any idea why in one case the getter is called first the the returned object is used for deserialization, in the other case the setter is called first with an object deserialized from scatch. That doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @mklein: sense and the XML Serializer don't actually mix. If you insist on knowing how this particular "sausage" is  made, then I recommend you look at the source code.

Comment: Re: "The reason for the behavior is that this is the way it has always worked." sounds like:
- Why you are always eat apples?
- The reason I eating apples is that I was always eating them